# Android ratingbar - how to preset Star Ratings

Tags: android, mysql, variables

I am aggregating numeric ratings (1-5 stars) from a MySQL table containing many entries.  It will take the average of the ratings in the column and return it as a variable into Android.

Let's call the variable $foo.

How do I use $foo to preset the Android RatingBar so that it will programmatically change the number of stars based on the database value?

Comment: I'm confused. By "as users vote" do you mean "as the database is updated"? If so, you will need to either find some way for the database to push you a notification that it has changed, or periodically poll the database for updates.

Comment: I do not want it THAT dynamic.  Just when the page/activity is created the first time.  A one time "value pre-set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RatingBar.setRating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setRating%28float%29).

```
float foo = 3.5;
RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
bar.setRating(foo);
```

Comment: In what way does this dynamically change the number of stars as users vote?

Comment: His answer is what I am looking for.  Thank you.  I was a bit confusing there in the end of the question.